# How to further optimize the python code having tensorflow + opencv + pyrealsense2

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, optimization, cython

## Current State

Right now, I have a python code that using `pyrealsense2`, `cv2`, `tensorflow` for reading a tensorflow model. I have cythonized it **without** changing the `.py` to `.pyx` *i.e* I haven't changed any variables with `cdef` since most of the variables are depending on the indicated libraries.

I have a research about using the `cdef` parts on *e.g* to `pyrealsense2` but the sources led me to nowhere. Only I was able to find is some `cv2` wrappers but it isn't enough for me. Furthermore, I'm a newcomer for `cython`. So, I have some difficulties to convert it to the `cython` too.

### Question is,

**Is it really possible to optimize and speed up the codes that have** `tensorflow + pyrealsense2 + cv2` ? I'm sure I can do something for the `cv2` part but the most important thing is to reduce the inference time of the model **as much as possible**.

## Examples and expected results

My goal is to convert *e.g* :

```
pipeline = rs.pipeline()
config_rs = rs.config()
config_rs.enable_stream(rs.stream.depth, 848, 480, rs.format.z16, FRAME_RATE)
config_rs.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 848, 480, rs.format.bgr8, FRAME_RATE)
frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
try:
    while True:


            depth_frame = frames.get_depth_frame()
            color_frame = frames.get_color_frame()

            if not depth_frame or not color_frame:
                continue
            depth_image = np.asanyarray(depth_frame.get_data())
            color_image = np.asanyarray(color_frame.get_data())
            x, y = sess.run([x_, y_], feed_dict={input_img: [depth_img]})
```

**into something like:**

```
cdef "type of this" pipeline = rs.pipeline()
cdef "type of this" config_rs = rs.config()
config_rs.enable_stream(rs.stream.depth, 848, 480, rs.format.z16, FRAME_RATE)
config_rs.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 848, 480, rs.format.bgr8, FRAME_RATE)
cdef "type of this" frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
try:
    while True:


            cdef "type of this" depth_frame = frames.get_depth_frame()
            cdef "type of this" color_frame = frames.get_color_frame()

            if not depth_frame or not color_frame:
                continue
            cdef "type of this" depth_image = np.asanyarray(depth_frame.get_data())
            cdef "type of this" color_image = np.asanyarray(color_frame.get_data())
            cdef "type of them" x, y = sess.run([x_, y_], feed_dict={input_img: [depth_img]})
```

## Further

First of all, thank you for help, I tend to optimize the `tensorflow + pyrealsense2` part but I would like to hear the suggestions for other types of optimizations (maybe that I haven't read about them).

**Note:** Some may suggest me to use TensorRT but sadly I'm on a Windows machine.

Comment: This honestly doesn't look like anything where `cdef` is going to help: all you're doing with the variables is passing them to other functions and so all you'd achieve by setting their types is to spend a little bit of time checking the types.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I will try that with a dummy juptyter notebook.

Comment: I don't think I made a suggestion? I just said "I don't think this will help"